# Can't redirect https for http

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Some versions of Chrome automatically add https to my site addres. So I need to redirect https to http, because I don't have SSL certificate. I'm trying this, with no result:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =https
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]  
</IfModule>
```

Comment: "Some versions of Chrome automatically add https to my site addres." - possibly because [HSTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) was implemented on your domain (at some point).

Answer (score 2):

Without having a certificate a browser can't speak HTTPS to your server and your server never has a chance to reply 301 to the browser.

In short, without a HTTPS server correctly configured including the certificate you can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

to redirect https trafic to http using .htaccess you can do

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule .* http://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

or

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$
RewriteRule .* http://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

but if google redirect trafic to https, it will make a redirect loop, so you may have to find why trafic is redirected to https (maybe cache, try another browser clean from any request)